# Jquery .post and form data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using .post to post my data to my controller. I would like to pass all the data that I have in a form. Is there an easy way to take all the form data and add it to the .post command to send it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use the .[serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) method.

```
var postData = $('#formId').serialize();
$.post(url,  postData);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("/url", $(this).serialize(), callbackFunction);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[jquery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) is what you need.